# Same endian machines but different outputs

Tags: memcmp

I have a piece of code and its generating different output when run on centOS and RHEL systems and both are little-endian machines.
RHEL: result is 0
Cent OS: result is -4

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned short U16;
typedef unsigned char U8; 
int main(void)
{
    U16 num1 = 1;
    U16 num2 = 5;
    short int ret;

    U8* s1 = (U8*)&num1;
    U8* s2 = (U8*)&num2;
    ret = memcmp((void*)s1, (void*)s2, (size_t) sizeof(U16));
    printf("result is %d\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

In both cases I am expecting output non-zero but its not. Also If I change 'ret' type to 'int' from 'short int' then output is non-zero for both cases. So, what's wrong when 'ret' declared as 'short int' ?

Comment: 1. Tag your question with a programming language.  2. Show the exact command line you used for compiling. If using an IDE, then reproduce the problem using the command-line toolset first.

Comment: onlinegdb.com gives -4.

Comment: programiz.com gives -4.

Comment: ideone.com gives -4.

Comment: compiled both as .c and .cpp for both gcc and g++ compilers
# g++ sample.cpp
#./a.out
result is -262144

# gcc sample.c
#./a.out
result is -262144

Comment: and did you run the exact same binaries on each machine, or did you recompile them on each machine?

Comment: recompiled on each machine separately. One machine installed with CentOS and another one with RHEL. Output on CentOS is -4 which is expected but on RHEL it's -262144 ( 0xfffc0000) which is strange and how to interpret this result ?

Comment: I revised my above comment:
recompiled on each machine separately. One machine installed with CentOS and another one with RHEL. Output on CentOS is -4 which is expected but on RHEL it's 0 but if I change ret to 'int' then the output is -262144 ( 0xfffc0000) which is strange and how to interpret this result ?